# Как настроить Nginx для нескольких доменов с поддержкой HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, nginx, https

Помогите настроить nginx для 2-х и более хостов с поддержкой HTTPS.
[image: схема сети]

```
Router - принимает запросы по HTTP и HTTPS.
Передает их на host A(10.200.1.10) на 80/443 порт

HostA (10.200.1.10) - nginx 1.10.3: принимает запросы на 80/443 портах.
Обслуживает: 
    www.site.ru (proxy_pass http://10.200.1.11:80) 
    sub.site.ru (proxy_pass http://10.200.1.12:80) 

HostB (10.200.1.11) - apache2 + WordPress 4.7.2 (www.site.ru)
HostC (10.200.1.12) - apache2 + php-script (sub.site.ru)
```

Проблем с sub.site.ru нет - приходящие запросы на 80 порт nginx переводит на https и все работает отлично. Проблемы делает wordpress - я получаю либо redirect-loop в /wp-admin/, либо redirect-loop в /, либо запросы редиректятся на https://sub.site.ru.

Здесь - http://pastebin.com/MWRukUun - полный конфиг для nginx. Эта версия конфига приводит к redirect-loop.

Как можно решить проблему? Она вообще решаема?

Comment: А что в wordpress в админке - Настройки - Общие - "Адрес WordPress (URL)" и "Адрес сайта (URL)"? Если админка перманентно недоступна, то что в базе - таблица `wp_options`, записи с `options_name=` `siteurl` и `home`? Картина очень похожа на неправильную смену домена в WP.

Comment: @KAGGDesign: да. я так делал. менял http:// на https:// - не помогало. только менялся тип redirect-loop : или на / или на wp-admin

Comment: А так нельзя с вордпрессом. У него все внутренние ссылки абсолютные, их надо все менять, иначе redirect loop.